# What is the problem with \usefonttheme{serif} in beamer for xepersian?

Tags: beamer, fonts, xepersian

In a beamer for working with xepersian package, I want the formula to be with English digit fonts, but with any command provided with the xerpersian package it doesn't work. Here is MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX 
% Commands for running this example:
% xelatex xepersian_intro_2016
% xelatex xepersian_intro_2016
% End of Commands
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagemode=FullScreen} 
{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usecolortheme{orchid} %1
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\usefonttheme{serif}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{xepersian}

%
%%%%تصحیح چپ‌چین شدن متن
%\raggedleft
\setlatintextfont[Scale=.9]{Times New Roman}


\settextfont{XB Yas}
\setmathdigitfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\DefaultMathsDigits

\title{یک عنوان}

\author{یک نویسنده}

\institute[]{یک موسسه }

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\begin{latin}
\begin{align*}
    y_2 = max_{y} P(y_1\vert x)
 \end{align*}
 \end{latin}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

When I comment, the command \usefonttheme{serif}, 
it shows what I want, English digits in the formulas but doesn't show Persian texts. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Something that could be useful

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagemode=FullScreen} 
{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usecolortheme{orchid} %1
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

%\usefonttheme{serif}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

%
%%%%تصحیح چپ‌چین شدن متن
%\raggedleft
\setlatintextfont[Scale=.9]{Times New Roman}


\settextfont{XB Yas}
\setmathdigitfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\DefaultMathsDigits

\title{یک عنوان}

\author{یک نویسنده}

\institute[]{یک موسسه }

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\begin{latin}
\begin{align*}
    y_2 = \max_{y} P(y_1\vert x)
 \end{align*}
 \end{latin}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```